# Weak wifi signal on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless

I have a weak wifi connection on my Ubuntu.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I am quite new to Ubuntu so don't know many commands. Is there any way to make the wifi signal stronger? When I had Windows the connection was so strong even in a different room and now it is low even in the same room of the Wifi router!

This is `sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: 68:f7:28:e3:76:88
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:31 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:f0904000-f0904fff memory:f0900000-f0903fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: ac:e0:10:2a:c9:e9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:34 memory:f0800000-f087ffff memory:f0880000-f088ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: ham0
       serial: 7a:79:19:3b:05:4f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full ip=25.59.5.79 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Comment: You have asked if there is a command that makes your Wi-Fi stronger.  The answer to *that* question is "No". Are you sure that the WiFi is actually weaker than it used to be, or is it possible that the strength indicator is just different between operating systems?  Also, WiFi is just plain inconsistent and can be affected by all sorts of uncontrollable variables